# how to restore default kde kwin on cmd?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, kubuntu, openbox, kwin

yesterday I restarted my Kubuntu 22.04 machine and now I have a problem. Normaly my login screen looks like this:
[image: default screen]

I am not 100% sure, but I changed nothing after installation, so i think its kwin. But now it looks like this:

[image: new screen (I dont like)]

I got these images from google. I can't change the session in the new screen. I even can't login. Its possible to open the diplay keyboard and enter pw, but i can't submit. So currently my only option to access my computer is recovery-mode and login as sudo, but there I cant enable network connection. Is there a command to restore my display settings back to default?

Comment: This just can't be **kwin**. More probably  SDDM (Simple Desktop Display Manager)

Comment: it was 100% this, https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Kubuntu_21.04_Desktop_en.png on homescreen, so if its not the same, the screenshot in post is the wrong system

Comment: I am more and more confused. What you now say 100% this is some typical kde-plasma desktop, that can be what you can see **after being logged in** however you write that you cannot even log in ??? Can you Ctrl+Alt+F1 and reach some text console on which you could log as root ?

Comment: sorry, yes I cant login on this openbox login screen. https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Kubuntu_21.04_Desktop_en.png was my desktop when everything was fine and its the desktop I want back

Comment: OK then since the pb appears to be with SDDM, you should check its configuration file. For this you need a way to log into your system. So : Do you get a mean to come back to console text mode (try Ctrl+Alt+F1 ou F2 or whatever) and then log as root ?

Comment: yes, I am in console via ctrl+alt+F2

Comment: But I dont have a folder /etc/sddm.conf. I have a /etc/sddm folder with a wayland and Xsession script in it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.